# Django - NoReverseMatch error in a simple form

Tags: python, django, web

i am stuck with this error:

"Reverse for 'create' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'$create$']"

I can't see where the problem is.

The log is an app in my general project

Here is my Project/log/templates/log/index.html that contain my form:

```
<form action="{% url 'log:create' %}" method="post">
//...
</form>
```

Here is the Project/Project/urls/py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', include('log.urls', namespace='log')),
url(r'^log/', include('log.urls', namespace='log')),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

Here is my Project/log/urls.py :

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
 url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
 url(r'^login$', views.login, name='login'),
 url(r'^logout$', views.logout, name='logout'),
 url(r'^create$', views.create, name='create'),
 ]
```

Then I defined my function create in the Project/log/views.py :

```
def create(request):
  if request.method == "POST" and request.POST['name'] and request.POST['password']:
      name_p = escape(request.POST['name'])
      pass_p = escape(request.POST['password'])
      try:
          login = User.objects.get(username=name_p)
      except:
          user = User.objects.create_user(name_p, name_p+'@email.com', pass_p)
          user.save()
          return HttpResponseRedirect('log:index')
      else:
          return render(request, 'log/index.html', {'error_message' : 'The login you chose already exists',})
  else:
      return render(request, 'log/index.html', {'error_message' : 'You did\'t fill the entire form',})
```

I don't know where is my mistake because the form is a simple one with no arguments passed and the regular expression in the url is a simple one too. It must be a problem in my function I think. If someone could lead me to the right path to fix this kind of error that would be great ;)

Comment: The urls.py is the main one or one that is included in the main?

Comment: Given the `urls.py` in your example, there is no namespace `log` for one, and your login, logout and create patterns need to have a `/` before the `$`

Comment: Show the line where you include this urls.py. I guess you put `$` before including this.

Comment: I modified my post to be clearer, then you can see the architecture of the project.

Comment: First off, remove the line `$` in `url(r'^$', include('log.urls', namespace='log'))`. Also, use different namespace names. The reverse URL resolver matches the first pattern, and is causing this confusion.

Comment: Thank You karthikr, i deleted this line and that fixed the problem. So if a want to do a global matching pattern, as i wanted to do, I need to do it in only one Regexp.